# Doubly-stochastic partial-isometric matrices

Tags: matrices, isometries, stochastic-matrices

An $n\times n$ matrix $A$ with nonegative real entries $a_{ij}$ is said to be *doubly stochastic* if $\sum_{i=1}^na_{ij} = 1$,
for all $j$, and  $\sum_{j=1}^na_{ij}=1$, for all $i$.

Much is known [1] about the algebraic structure of the semigroup  $\Omega _n$ formed by all doubly stochastic $n\times n$ matrices.  For
example, permutation matrices are the only  invertible doubly stochastic matrices whose inverse is also doubly stochastic.
On the other hand [3],  the idempotent elements in $\Omega _n$ are precisely the direct sums of $k\times k$ matrices of the form
$$
  \pmatrix{
    1/k & 1/k & \ldots & 1/k \cr
    \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\cr
    1/k & 1/k & \ldots & 1/k \cr}
  $$
together with their conjugates by permutation matrices.

> Question:  Which doubly stochastic matrices are partial isometries
> (i.e. satisfy the equation $AA^tA = A$)?

See [2] for the characterization of **normal**, partial isometric, doubly stochastic matrices.

[1] *Farahat, H. K.*, [**The semigroup of doubly-stochastic matrices**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1017/S2040618500035401), Proc. Glasg. Math. Assoc. 7, 178-183 (1966). [ZBL0156.26001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0156.26001).

[2] *Prasada Rao, P. S. S. N. V.*, On generalized inverses of doubly stochastic matrices, Sankhyā, Ser. A 35, 103-105 (1973). [ZBL0301.15005](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0301.15005).

[3] *Sinkhorn, R.*, [**Two results concerning doubly stochastic matrices**](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/2313782), Am. Math. Mon. 75, 632-634 (1968). [ZBL0162.04205](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0162.04205).

Comment: @ChrisRamsey But I think the equation in the question describes an isometry. I think the right equation is $(AA^t)^2=AA^t$, right?

Comment: @vidyarthi Any doubly stochastic idempotent will be a partial isometry. The OP gives a description of the idempotents and most are not permutations.

Comment: @ChrisRamsey see my answer now.

Comment: @vidyarthi, here are two results from Halmos' "A Hilbert Space Problem Book", which say that the two characterizations are equivalent: (Problem 127) A bounded linear transformation $U$ is a partial isometry if and only if $U^*U$ is a projection, and (Corollary 3) A bounded linear transformation $U$ is a partial isometry if and only if $U = UU^*U$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is an attempt to validate the conclusion proposed by
@vidyarthi.

> Theorem:  Every
> doubly-stochastic partial-isometric matrix is the product of a
> permutation matrix and a doubly-stochastic projection.

Proof:
Given a doubly-stochastic partial-isometric matrix $A$, one has that $A^tA$ and $AA^t$ are doubly-stochastic
projections, so by Theorem 2 in (*Sinkhorn, R.*, [**Two results concerning doubly stochastic matrices**](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/2313782), Am. Math. Mon. 75, 632-634 (1968). [ZBL0162.04205](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0162.04205)) there are permutation matrices  $U$ and $V$ such that
$$
  U^tA^tAU = P(k_1)\oplus P(k_2)\oplus \cdots \oplus P(k_n)
  $$
and
$$
  V^tAA^tV = P(l_1)\oplus P(l_2)\oplus \cdots \oplus P(l_m),
  $$
where, for any integer $k$,
$$
  P(k):=
  \pmatrix{
    1/k & 1/k & \ldots & 1/k \cr
    \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\cr
    1/k & 1/k & \ldots & 1/k \cr}.
  $$
Replacing $A$ with $V^tAU$, we may assume that $U$ and $V$ coincide with the identity matrix and hence $U$ and $V$ will henceforth
be ommitted.

Set $c(k)=(1/\sqrt k,1/\sqrt k,…,1/\sqrt k) ∈ \mathbb R^k$, so that $c(k)$ is a unit vector spanning the range of $P(k)$.
Moreover  the range of the
projection   $A^tA$ above admits an orthonormal basis formed by the vectors
$$
  u_1 = c(k_1)\oplus 0_{k_2}\oplus \cdots \oplus 0_{k_n},
  $$
$$
  u_2 = 0_{k_1}\oplus c(k_2)\oplus \cdots \oplus 0_{k_n},
  $$
$$...$$
$$
  u_n = 0_{k_1}\oplus 0_{k_2}\oplus \cdots \oplus c(k_n),
  $$
a similar reasoning yielding a basis $\{v_1, v_2, …, v_m\}$ for the range of  $AA^t$.  The initial and final
projections of a partial isometry share rank, so $n=m$, and we claim that, up to a permutation of indices $i$, one has
that  $k_i=l_i$, for all $i$.

Notice that  $A$ maps $\hbox{span}\{u_i\}$ isometrically onto $\hbox{span}\{v_i\}$ so, for $i\neq j$, one has that
$Au_i$ and $Au_j$  are orthogonal vectors.  However these vectors have nonnegative coordinates so their support (set of
indices for nonzero coordinates) must be  disjoint.  By the pigeonhole principle each $u_i$ must therefore be mapped
under $A$ to a scalar
multiple of some $v_j$.  By positivity and norm preservation these scalars must coincide with 1 so there is a permutation $\sigma $ such that $Au_i=v_{\sigma (i)}$, for all $i$.

Observe that, being doubly-stochastic, $A$ leaves invariant the linear functional $\Sigma$ which sums all of the coordinates of a vector.  Noticing that $\Sigma(u_i)=\sqrt{k_i}$, while $\Sigma(v_j)=\sqrt{l_j}$, we deduce that $k_i=l_{\sigma (i)}$.

It is now easy to see that there exists a permutation matrix $W$ such that $Wu_i = v_{\sigma (i)}$.  Letting
$$
  B=W^tA,
  $$
we then have that $Bu_i=u_i$, while $B^tB=A^tA$.

It follows that $B$ is a partial isometry coinciding with the identity operator on its initial space, and hence that $B$ coincides with its initial projection $B^tB$.  This leads to
$$
  A=WB=WB^tB=WA^tA.
  $$

Comment: In the last statement, I think you concluded that each block of $A$ is $P(n)$ instead of $A=P(n)$, right?

Comment: by the way, I have modified my answer similarly. See if it helps

Comment: “... you concluded that each block of  is () instead of =(), right?”  Yep!  This is what I meant by  “Dealing with each block separately...”

Comment: Here is the desired counterexample: we have the product of $\frac1{3}\begin{pmatrix}1&1&1\\1&1&1\\1&1&1\end{pmatrix}$ and $\frac1{3}\begin{pmatrix}-1&2&2\\2&-1&2\\2&2&-1\end{pmatrix}$ to be a stochastic partial isometric matrix $\frac1{3}\begin{pmatrix}1&1&1\\1&1&1\\1&1&1\end{pmatrix}$. Hence, your argument (as well as mine before) fails. Modified my answer

Comment: @vidyarthi, If I understand it right you are claiming that the third matrix in your message is a counter-example.  If so I don't think I agree because this matrix is itself a doubly stochastic projection.

Comment: No, I meant the second of the matrix has negative entries, and hence is not a permutation matrix, and not stochastic, so your fist statement is thus wrong

Comment: @vidyarthi, I understand you have shown one way to decompose the 3rd matrix which does not filfill the conditions in my statement, but I am sure you can find another decomposition which works!

Comment: ok, but then I think you should change your answer to just " Every doubly stochastic matrix **can be written** as a product of a doubly stochastic projection with a  permutation matrix" instead of "**is**"

Comment: @vidyarthi, I'd say most people would take "is" as a synonym to "can be written as".  For example I believe that it is standard to say that every positive integer "is"  the product of finitely many primes, even though often an integer may also be written as a product of numbers that are not prime.

Comment: so shall I delete my answer?

Comment: In my opinion your argument does not prove the result.  On the other hand deleting your answer is entirely up to you.

Comment: no, since you refer to me in your answer, so I thought of asking you before deleting

Comment: @vidyarthi, If your question is whether deleting your post would adversely affect my answer, the answer is no.

Answer (score -1):

From [here](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/jres/71B/jresv71Bn4p225_A1b.pdf), we have that a square matrix is a partial isometry if and only if it is of the form $A=UD=EU$, where $D, E$ are idempotent and $U$ is unitary. Translating this to our case, we have that a doubly stochatic matrix is a partial isometry when it is a product of an orthogonal matrix (scaled by a scalar) with an idempotent matrix  (again scaled by appropriate scalar) both of whose row and column sums equals $1$. The rank of the matrix equals that of the unscaled idempotent matrix.

To further elaborate as to why the unscaled matrices $E,D,U$ have the said property, suppose $A=EU$, where $E$ is idempotent and $U$ be unitary (orthogonal), we obtain, for the eigenvector $v=(1\ 1\ 1\ldots\ 1)^t$ of $A$, we get that $Av=v\implies EUv=v=E^2Uv=E(EUv)=Ev$, thereby showing that $v$ is an eigenvector of $E$ with eigenvalue $1$, thereby clearly implying $E$ has row sum of each row equal to $1$. A similar reasoning with the transpose of $A$ shows that $E$ should also have each column sum equal to $1$, since $E^t$ is also idempotent. Now, using that $A=UD$, and the  vector $v^t$ as a left eigenvector , we obtain that both $D$ and $U$ also have both row and column sum equal to $1$.

Comment: I do not see why $U$, $D$, and $E$ must be doubly stochastic.  But the guess is certainly very interesting!

Comment: @Ruy yes, they need not be. Added the scaling factors

Comment: Now I should say that I do not  see why , , and  must be scalar multiples of doubly stochastic matrices.

Comment: I think I can prove that your conclusion is corrrect, but the proof is a bit envolving.   Will try to write it down soon.

Comment: I think this is not yet correct.  The matrix
  $
  E={1\over30}\pmatrix{ 25&  -5&  10 \cr
   -5&  25&  10 \cr
   10&  10&  10}
  $
is idempotent and has $(1,1,1)$ as a fixed point and yet it is not doubly-stochastic.

Comment: @Ruy as I said, the discussion in the second discussion applies to unscaled matrices, that is, the row and column sums are same for the matrix. The matrix you gave as an example is definetely doubly stochastic. The row and column sums are all $1$

Comment: Stochastic matrices must have nonnegative entries (which often represent transition probabilities).

Comment: @Ruy thanks. edited the post. see now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111282/discussion-between-ruy-and-vidyarthi).